# Serving from different directories for Internet Explorer

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, internet-explorer

We have two different versions of our website - one for older versions of Internet Explorer (7 and 8), and one for all other browsers.

*(arguments around JS feature detection have been made, but we have found it easier to progress this way!)*

We would like to silently (ie without a 301) files to be served from a different directory - so a request to:

```
/app/foo/bar
```

would be served from the directory:

```
html/ie/foo/bar
```

for Internet Explorer 8 and below, and for other browsers from:

```
html/other/foo/bar
```

Is this possible to achieve using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

I've done it with the following (with a slight change to the directory structure):

```
/app/
  - index.html (for modern browsers)
  - .htaccess (with remapping for IE 6-8)
  /ie
    - index.html and other files
    - .htaccess (to turn off further remapping efforts)
```

The contents of `.htaccess` in `/app` is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/ie/$1 [PT]
```

The contents of `.htaccess` in `/app/ie` is:

```
RewriteEngine off
```